# VueJS: Appending a component programatically to a $ref element

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have dynamic list of 'posts' where I wanted to truncate the text (if it goes beyound a certain # of lines) and show a **Read More** button that users can click to show the entire text.

In VueJS, I decided to attach a `ref` to the div I want to append the button to (if the text is truncated).

The component is just a button really but it has some stylings and behaviors I want to copy over. The reason why this got more complicated then it needs to (bad thing?) is because I'm doing the truncating with CSS. I understand that using Javascript might have been easier.

So anyways, how can I dynamically add a component to this div (or its parent) using Javascript only? My own reference to the location would be the `ref` item.

```
// code after the promise of getting the posts has resolved in the created() hook
.then(() => {
  const posts = this.$refs.posts
  posts.forEach(p => {
    if (this.Overflown(f)) {
      // I want to attach a component (AwesomeButtonComponent) to this p div.
    }
  }
})
```

And for clarity:

HTML:

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
  <div class="postBody ref="posts">{{ post.body }}</div>
</div>
```

```
isOverflown(el) {
  return el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight || el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth;
}
```

The CSS that is truncating the text

```
.postsBody {
  white-space: pre-line;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

ALTERNATIVE POSSIBILITIES:

This button will only have ONE functionality, so it being a component is not important and adding styling isn't so difficult.

```
.then(() => {
  const announcementBodies = this.$refs.announcementBody;
    announcementBodies.forEach(a => {
      if (this.isOverflown(a)) {
        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerText = 'Click Me';
        button.onClick = 'doThis';
        a.parentElement.appendChild(button);
      }
});
```

In which case the difficult part would be to add a `v-on:click` directive to that button and then target that specific tag to remove the `clamp` css attribute.

Comment: Did you tought about a computed property like ```post.isOverflow```. After ```{{post.body}}``` add ```<button v-show="post.isOverflow"></button>```. Maybe this path can solve your problem without dealing with $refs.

Comment: issue is that this is a dynamic list so would that work?

Comment: Sure it will. When you will splice or push new post in your posts variable, they will be render. I can write an answer with some suggestion on how to achieve this.

Comment: Go for that, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Following our discussion into comments, I'll show you 2 way you can do this and try to explain the difference between them and let you decide how you will achieve this.

**EXAMPLE ONE**

The first example is the shortest I could do. This will need every post to have an isOverflow attribute. There is many way to do it client or server side. The other example will not need it.

```
<div v-for="post in posts">
    {{(post.isOverflow == true) ? post.body.substring(0,3)+'...' : post.body}} <button v-on:click="post.isOverflow = !post.isOverflow">{{(post.isOverflow == true) ? 'SHOW MORE' : 'SHOW LESS'}}</button>
</div>
```

This is not beautiful, but it work and it let you understand that you can manipulate the post inside the v-for. Each button will be automatically associate with the right post, so when you will click it, only the post associated will be affected.

**EXAMPLE TWO**

The other example i'll give you is by creating a new component for each post. Let's start with the v-for:

```
<post-component v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" v-bind:post="post"></post-component>
```

And the new component:

```
<template>
    <div v-bind:class="{'postsBody': isOverflow}">
        {{post.body}}
        <button v-on:click="changeState()">{{(post.isOverflow) ? 'SHOW LESS' : 'SHOW MORE'}}</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        props: {
            post:{}
        },

        data() {
            return {
                isOverflow: true
            }
        },

        methods: {
            changeState: function() {
                this.isOverflow = !this.isOverflow;
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style> //Please, put this in a CSS file, it's only for the example purpose.
.postsBody {
    white-space: pre-line;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

**CONCLUSION**

In the end, both of them will have the same result. The difference is what you prefer. I tried to show you two different way to let you understand how things work with Vue. Let me know if you need more explanations.